# What is wrong with laravel query builder query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-query-builder

I have written a query to fetch the data from mysql database using laravel query builder. Take a look at query builder code given below:

```
$products = DB::table("products as p")
                ->select("p.*")
                ->join("product_tag as pt", "pt.p_id", "p.id")
                ->whereIn("pt.tag_name", function($q1) use($request){
                    $q1->from("user_questionnaire as uc")
                            ->select(DB::raw("distinct(at.prod_tag)"))
                            ->join("questionnaire_answers as qa", function($join){
                                $join->on("qa.question_id", "=", "uc.question_id")
                                        ->where("qa.answer_number", "=", "uc.answer_id");
                            })
                            ->join("answer_tags as at", "at.answer_id", "qa.id")
                            ->where("uc.user_id", $request->user_id);
                })->get();
```

When i log this query builder, i get below response:

```
[
    {
        "query": "select `p`.* from `products` as `p` inner join `product_tag` as `pt` on `pt`.`p_id` = `p`.`id` where `pt`.`tag_name` in (select distinct(at.prod_tag) from `user_questionnaire` as `uc` inner join `questionnaire_answers` as `qa` on `qa`.`question_id` = `uc`.`question_id` and `qa`.`answer_number` = ? inner join `answer_tags` as `at` on `at`.`answer_id` = `qa`.`id` where `uc`.`user_id` = ?)",
        "bindings": [
                  "uc.answer_id",
                  115
        ],
        "time": 0.43
    }
]
```

Now when i run this query in phpmyadmin, it returns desired results. But when print_r `$products` variable, it displays empty array(`[]`).

Please suggest what i am doing wrong in query builder.

Comment: `uc.answer_id` is being added as a binding. So your query is checking if your `qa.answer_number` matches the string `uc.answer_id` which is probably not what you intended. Try changing the innermost `->where(...)` to another `->on(...)` clause.

Comment: Thanks **@Jonathan** it worked flawlessly.

Comment: No problem, I've added an answer just for completeness :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using a `->where()` to apply extra criteria to your innermost join:

```
->where("qa.answer_number", "=", "uc.answer_id");
```

In this case, the 3rd parameter is being bound into the query as a string so your database will be comparing the `qa.answer_number` field to the string `uc.answer_id` which is probably not what you're looking for. When you do a `where`, the 3rd (or the 2nd if you omit the operator) will always be added to the query bindings which is what results in this behaviour.

To get around this, you should use another `->on(...)` to add additional criteria to the join:

```
$join->on("qa.question_id", "=", "uc.question_id")
     ->on("qa.answer_number", "=", "uc.answer_id");
```

That will make sure that the database is comparing columns to columns rather than columns to values.

Comment: Nice **@Jonathan**. Thanks for explanation too.